# unicode символы в переменных

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode

Можно ли как-то в `gcc` использовать названия переменных с `unicode` символами? Разрешено ли это стандартом?

Например:

```
auto π = 3.14159265;
auto α = sin(π / 4);
```

Comment: похоже, что нет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) приведена таблицы символов юникода, которые можно, и которые нельзя использовать в качестве идентификаторов переменных. [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586368/can-c-variables-in-cpp-file-defined-as-special-symbols-%CE%B2) на английском stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по тому, что написано в стандарте об идентификаторах ([ссылка](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers)), символы юникода можно использовать в качестве идентификаторов переменных, за исключением символов следующих диапазонов

> U+0300-U+036F, U+1DC0-U+1DFF, U+20D0-U+20FF, U+FE20-U+FE2F

Греческие буквы (диапазон `U+0370-U+03FF`) не попадают в эти диапазоны, так что теоретически их можно использовать. Однако на английском stackoverflow [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586368/can-c-variables-in-cpp-file-defined-as-special-symbols-%CE%B2), что некоторые компиляторы не поддерживают такую опцию.

В gcc 8.2 с ключом `-std=c++17` программа с такими идентификаторами не компилируется, в Clang 7.0 с ключом `-std=c++17` компилируется нормально.

Comment: в gcc не работает. clang - работает.

Comment: Блин, ну да. Пока прочитал, что в стандарте написано, уже и забыл, что речь про `gcc` шла. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: так как в gcc сделать?

Comment: По всей видимости пока никак, т.к. в `gcc` нет поддержки символов юникода в качестве идентификаторов.